# Facebook Javascript SDK: username not indexable

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

Is this a bug now too? I know theres a name index bug, but now I can't even do it with username. Am I doing this right?

```
FB.api('fql?q=SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username="'+username+'"',
        function(response){
            console.dir(response);
        });
}
```

I'm getting:

> "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an
>   indexable column."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try encoding the query before using, like:

```
var qry = 'fql?q=' + escape('SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username="'+username+'"');
FB.api(qry,
        function(response){
            console.dir(response);
        });
}

OR the other way
FB.api(
  {
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username="'+username+'"'
  },
  function(response) {
    console.dir(response);
  }
);
```

Hope it helps